# Loop repeats despite conditions being met

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements

I want my `while` loop to stop whenever the user enters 1 or 2. If anything else is entered then it should repeat. I tried putting an exclamation mark before the variable name and using an equality sign. I tried using a single or operator.

The `petId` variable is getting the right numbers -- I see the `NSLog()`s for "Dog" and "Cat". Why is the loop looping despite having a 1 or 2 entered?

```
int petId;
while(petId != 1 || petId!=2)
        {
            NSLog(@"%d",petId);
            NSLog(@"Would you like to create a dog or a cat?\n1.Dog 2.Cat");
            //Scan user input
            scanf("%i",&petId);
            if(petId == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Dog");
            }
            else if(petId==2)
            {
                NSLog(@"Cat");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Invalid Entry");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is C and not specific to Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably made a mistake in the boolean operators:
Replace

```
while(petId != 1 || petId!=2)
```

With

```
while(petId != 1 && petId!=2)
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, you'll kick yourself.

The `||` means OR.  If EITHER expression is true: `(petId != 1)` OR `(petId != 2)`, then the loop will continue.

- If `petID == 1` then `petID != 2` is true.
- If `petID == 2` then `petID != 1` is true.
- If `petID == 3` then both are true.

You're looking for `&&`.

```
while (exp1 && exp2) { ...
```

Then the loop will continue as long as `petId` is not 1 and not 2.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is 2, then it is not 1.

If your input is 1, then it is not 2.

Therefore your (petId != 1 || petId!=2) condition is always true.

Replace it with (petId != 1 && petId!=2) and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

The expression `petId != 1 || petId!=2` is true if `petId` is not equal to 1 *or* it is not equal to 2 - and as it cannot be both 1 and 2 at the same time this expression is always true...

Try `petId != 1 && petId != 2`